# How to grep git log insertions?

Tags: git

I want to look for commits where I have introduced functions for the first time to ensure they are covered by unit tests.

I know about the pickaxe,

```
git log -Sfunction -p --author="ZenLikeThat"
```

gets me close to what I am after but I only want to search through insertions with the pickaxe, not deletions.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about grepping the diff:

```
git log -Sfunction -p | egrep '^commit: |^+.*function'
```